# check-and-set action on redis cluster php

Tags: php, redis, cluster-computing, predis

I'm using a clustered redis. All I want to do is adding a new value to a limited set.

This is my code:

```
$redis->watch(keyMem)
$count = $redis->scard($keyMem);
if($count < $limit) 
$redis->multi()
  ->sadd($keyMem, $value)
  ->exec();
```

and I get:

> "cannot use 'watch' over clusters of connections."

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any solution and i coded my own lock.

```
$keyLock = $keyMem."lock";
$start_time = microtime();
while(true){
  if($redis->setnx($keyLock, "1")){
    $count = $redis->scard($keyMem);
    if(i$count < $limit){
        $r = $tredis->sadd($keyMem, $value);
    }
    $redis->del($keyLock);
  }
  else{
    if(microtime() - $start_time > 0.05){
      $tredis->del($keyLock);
    }
  }
}
```